# Как вывести Set массив добавляя значения через Input. У меня не получается выходит в console.log [object set]

Tags: javascript

```
let s2 = new Set()
let inp = +document.querySelector('.i-2').value;
let out = '';

function f2() {
    out += s2.add(inp);
    console.log(out);
    
}

document.querySelector('.b-2').onclick = f2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Значения можно взять с помощью метода **[values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values)**, т.е.

```
console.log(s2.values());
```